# Eclipse - debug a test suite launched through GNU Make

Tags: eclipse, debugging, makefile

I am working on a C project in Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu. The project has some test suites invoking a binary `run_tests` with different command-line parameters. The test suites are defined with Makefiles and invoked by running `make check` in the project root.

My goal is to set up a debugging configuration in Eclipse for debugging the test suites. I want to have the following workflow:

1. Set a breakpoint in `run_tests`
2. Launch debug configuration to run test suites
3. See the breakpoint being hit inside Eclipse

How can I achieve this?

**My thoughts so far**

1. It is easy to set up a debug configuration to directly run `run_tests` without using `make`. However, this will force me to manually configure the command line parameters which `make check` should figure out for me.
2. I could edit the makefile rule to run `gdb --args run_tests arg1 arg2` instead of `run_tests arg1 arg2`. However, will Eclipse recognise and integrate with that `gdb` instance?
3. On Windows, I could edit the makefile rule to run `vsjitdebugger run_tests arg1 arg2`. Is there an equivalent to `vsjitdebugger` for Eclipse on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. Create a "C/C++ application" debug configuration
2. Set the C/C++ application to "/usr/bin/make"
3. Set the command-line argument to "check"
4. Write the following to the *gdbinit* file:

   ```
   set detach-on-fork off
   set target-async on
   set non-stop on
   set pagination off

   # Not necessary but improves performance
   set auto-solib-add off
   ```

Note: this solution can be painfully slow, as gdb will follow every fork initiated by `make`. For example, if `make` spawns `/bin/cp` 1000 times to copy setup files, then gdb will debug every one of those processes.